# Is there any set of circles on the plane that satisfies the following conditionEvery direct line on the plane crosses at least one most 100 circles

Tags: geometry, soft-question

**Is there any set of circles on the plane that satisfies the following condition?
Every direct line on the plane crosses at least one and at most 100 circles.**

This is the problem I faced when I was preparing for IMO. And if we consider dots as circles with 0 of radius, then such set actually exists We can align dots on every point on the curve of $y = x^3$ Then it is trivial that every direct line crosses at, at least 1 and at most 3 dots on the curve.

What about if we exclude dots?